# padding remain after decryption

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I want to encrypt and decrypt string using AES CBC but the problem is the padding remain after decryption ;

```
key="wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"; 
iv="1111111111111111";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("60000", key, { iv: iv , padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  });
console.log("mmh-dec",decrypted.toString());
```

I got "3630303030" instead of 60000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding is missing when converting the bytes to string.

```
decrypted.toString()
```

should be:

```
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

Example snippet:

```js
key="wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"; 
iv="1111111111111111";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("60000", key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});

console.log("mmh-dec",decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```